# Powershell built in commands stopped working

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I need some help trying to troubleshoot my Powershell.
All started when Formatter won't work on newly created file in VS Code.
I restarted all instances of VS Code - and it stopped working everywhere.
I tried to disable and re-install powershell extension - nothing.
VS Code froze on "Starting Powershell.." in bottom right corner and when clicked it says:

```
Running the contributed command: 'PowerShell.ShowSessionMenu' failed.
```

When I start Powershell console or Powershell ISE even as Admin, half of the commands not working:

```
Write-Host : The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-Host "test"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Laptop updated to KB4592449 4 days ago and instances of Code and Powershell ISE that I was using normally until today were running since then,

Any idea what happened and how to fix?

Update: Everything returned to norm after I uninstalled Powershell 7 AND PowerToys. Not sure which one helped.

Update2: Nope, after couple of hours same symptoms.

Update3: Troubleshooting further. Ran `(Get-Command -type cmdlet Write-Host).ModuleName` on a healthy computer, got `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`
Ran `Get-Module "Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility"` on bad computer - no output, meaning module is not loaded. because on healthy computer it did show some output for that module. Why is not this module imported?
If I say `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` on bad computer, `Write-Host` starts working again.
Why is it not autoloading as always?

Comment: What's the output from `winrm get winrm/config/Winrs`? (you can run it from an elevated `cmd.exe`)

Comment: WSManFault
   
and 
Error number:  -2144108526 0x80338012
The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".